# Decrease space between columns in multicols and tcolorbox

Tags: multicol

I want to decrease space between columns and display `tcolorbox` without frame.

My Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}
\posterbox[width=12.0cm,height=5.0cm]{xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm}
{
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{0.1cm}
{
\begin{tcolorbox}
\setlength\columnsep{-10pt}
%\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0.5mm]
\item  ............ 
\item  ............ 
\item  ............ 
\item  ............ 
\item  ............ 
\item  ............ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{tcolorbox}
} 
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `\usepackage[a4,landscape]{geometry}` is invalid: the option you want is called `a4paper`, not `a4`.

Second, you have an overfull `\hbox` of width `\parindent` due to the indentation box inserted when you do `\begin{tcbposter}`. Adding `\noindent` before `\begin{tcbposter}` fixes this problem.

Now, to the real questions. Since you didn't say what to do with the removed horizontal space, I had to guess: I'll assume you want to keep the whole overall width and completely fill it with the column contents (thus, I set `\columnsep` to `0pt`).

1. In order to remove the frame around the `tcolorbox`, you can use the `tile` option, which is a shortcut for `skin=tile` (this normally requires `\tcbuselibrary{skins}`).
2. The horizontal space you are trying to squeeze does not come from `multicol`'s `\columnsep` parameter—that is why your attempt with `\setlength\columnsep{-10pt}` doesn't work. It comes in part from the `enumitem` horizontal spacing parameters—mainly from `labelwidth`, but also a bit from the by default automatically-computed `labelindent`. Also, your dots don't necessary fill a whole line, since you are using an explicit `............` instead of `\dotfill`.

   By passing `leftmargin=*` to the `enumerate` environment, one tells `enumitem` 1) to set `labelwidth` to the width of `0.` (this is due to the `\arabic` numbering of the enumeration) and 2) to compute the `leftmargin` parameter from the others. Since `labelindent` defaults to `0pt` when it is not computed from the other parameters, which is the case when one uses `leftmargin=*`, the `enumerate` labels are then set to start at the left margin of the current column.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster, skins}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\noindent     % Without this, you have an overfull \hbox (\parindent too much)
\begin{tcbposter}
\posterbox[width=12.0cm,height=5.0cm]{xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm}
{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[tile]       % <---- 'tile' removes the frame
  \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0.5mm, leftmargin=*]
  \item  \dotfill\\ abc def\dotfill
  \item  \dotfill\\\mbox{}\dotfill
  \item  \dotfill\\\mbox{}\dotfill
  \item  \dotfill\\\mbox{}\dotfill
  \item  \dotfill\\\mbox{}\dotfill
  \item  \dotfill\\\mbox{}\dotfill
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{tcolorbox}
}%
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: it is not very clear why you need the `tcolorbox` here. Without it, you'd obtain the following (i.e., no more `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` margins from the `tcolorbox`):

[image]